# Getting multiple values out of a key in hashtable

Tags: javascript, json, hashtable

I have an output from an API which gives multiple value want them to prettify as an indivual output in javascript

```
[
    {
        "key": "Time",
        "value": "\nTuesday, July 30, 2019 5:34:16 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 3:23:20 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 1:54:05 PM"
    }
]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to parse the data returned by the API you are consuming? To what format?

Comment: So many misunderstandings with the site here :( Generally SO requires a default level of research for this. If you had, you would have probably found `.split` at MDN. SO also requires that there be more than just a description of work to do. There needs to be a problem to solve, not a job to complete. In the future, please try to consider that the system here is setup to help you solve problems, not to do the work for you.

Comment: Take  a few minutes to read through [ask]. Then edit the question explaining what the output is that you want as well as showing us whatever you have tried to resolve the issue yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
const data = [
  {
    "key": "Time",
    "value": "\nTuesday, July 30, 2019 5:34:16 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 3:23:20 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 1:54:05 PM"
  }
];

let items = data[0].value.split("\n"); // Splits value between "\n", making an array
for (let item of items){ // Loops through items in the array, processing each in turn
  if(item.length > 0){ // Ignores items that are empty strings
    myDiv.innerHTML += item + "<br />"; // Adds the item and a line break to the div
  }
}
```

```html
<div id= "myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get individual data, for example day, key etc. you can make something like this:

```
const apiValue = [{
        "key": "Time",
        "value": "\nTuesday, July 30, 2019 5:34:16 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 3:23:20 PM\nMonday, July 29, 2019 1:54:05 PM"
    }]
const key = apiValue[0].key;
const day = apiValue[0].value.split('\n')[1].split(',')[0]
```

Comment: prints out only Tuesday instead of all three with day,date and time

Comment: yes, i know, it was only example of code you can use